# Exportar Excel con maatwebsite/excel 3.1 Laravel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite

tengo un descargar excel, que con libreria 2.1 me funcionaba sin inconvenientes

```
public function download(Request $request){
    $File="Archivo Primario";

    $data=array(
        array("NRO","PATERNO","MATERNO","NOMBRE","EDAD","EMAIL","NACIONALIDAD")
    );

    $usuario=User::where('tipo', '=', 1)
        ->orderBy("paterno")
        ->get();

    foreach ($usuario as $row){

        array_push($data, array(
            $row->nro,
            $row->paterno,
            $row->materno,
            $row->nombres,
            $row->edad,
            $row->email,
            $row->nacionalidad

        ));
    }

    Excel::create($File, function ($excel) use ($data) {
        $excel->sheet('Datos', function ($sheet) use ($data) {
            $sheet->fromArray($data, null, 'A1', false, false);
        });

    })->export('xls');
}
```

Pero se a actualizado mi librería de Excel a 3.1 y se que create dejó de funcionar, ahora puedo utilizar Excel::create() o Excel::store(), pero aqui viene mi consulta, como puedo lograr traspasar mi mismo codigo a la nueva librería.

Por favor ayuda, gracias

Comment: `Excel::create()` se ha eliminado y se reemplazado por `Excel::download/Excel::store($yourExport)`. Puedes seguir la guía que está en la documentación https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/upgrade.html#upgrading-to-3-from-2-1

Comment: Ok, gracias, disculpa mi ignorancia, porque estoy hace poco trabajando  con laravel, yo cree composer requiere maatwebsite/excel, debo instalar algo más para poder hacer uso de las nuevas funciones?

Comment: Cuál es el nombre del modelo que quieres exportar?

Comment: Por modelo te refieres a Excel::download()/Excel::store()

Comment: He actualizado mi codigo completo, mi $data es un array

Comment: Ah, disculpa que me salté lo que me preguntaste en el comentario. Si corriste el comando `composer requiere maatwebsite/excel` y no te dió ningún error, y tu sistema cumple todos los [requerimientos](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html) que tiene la librería; sí, ya puedes hacer uso de las nuevas funciones. Escribí una respuesta con lo básico para exportar un array a excel.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear la siguiente clase en `app/Exports`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;

class ArchivoPrimarioExport implements FromArray
{
    protected $data;

    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function array(): array
    {
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

Y en tu Controlador:

```
public function download (Request $request) 
{
    // deja tal cuál todo lo que tienes para crear el array
    // ...

    // quita esta parte:

    // Excel::create($File, function ($excel) use ($data) {
    //     $excel->sheet('Datos', function ($sheet) use ($data) {
    //         $sheet->fromArray($data, null, 'A1', false, false);
    //     });
    // })->export('xls');

    // y agrega lo siguiente:

    $export = new ArchivoPrimarioExport($data);

    return Excel::download($export, $File.'.xlsx');
}
```

También en el Controlador tendrás que importar esas clases agregando las siguientes líneas arriba:

```
use App\Exports\ArchivoPrimarioExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
```

Referencias: Laravel Excel [Usar arrays](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html#using-arrays)

Comment: Dale amigo, gracias, efectivamente no me arrojo ningun error, asi que ahora probaré